# Chrome incognito window greyed out why?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I installed Google Chrome without administrator privileges. It does not allow me to open an incognito window. However if I install with admin privileged, this is fine.

Why does this happen? I am suspecting that it has something to do with the registry, but why would Google Chrome need admin privileges to make a browser window that only doesn't log history? (especially if `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is writable without privileges)

Answer (score 1):

Under `HKCU\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome` check if you have the [**IncognitoModeAvailability**](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#IncognitoModeAvailability) DWORD set to **1**.

Might also want to check for the deprecated [**IncognitoEnabled**](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#IncognitoEnabled) DWORD while you're there.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get Incognito enabled for a Standard Local Account on a Win8 machine. But some of the things I tried may work others:

For me, both HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and HKEY_LOCAL_USER only had up to --> Software --> Policies. No Google folder. If this is the case for you, use Edit --> New --> Key To create the Google then Chrome folders.

I only made my keys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE since I wanted all users on the machine to have incognito available.

As for the IncognitoModeAvailability DWORD, I tried all 3 values. They are, using the link Karan provided:

- 0 = Incognito mode available
- 1 = Incognito mode disabled
- 2 = Incognito mode forced

Even with forced Incognito it was still grayed out for me, but maybe your mileage will differ.